# Inspect shows ??? in Rad Studio 10.3.2

Tags: c++builder

Rad Studio 10.3.2, create a new Windows VCL app C++. Put a breakpoint at the Form1 constructor. If I inspect "this" and the debugger shows ???? for any variable.

I am having really a lot of problems with 10.3.2, not only this one (std::variant not work, CLANG stops, ...). I would say that it has a lot of bugs but now I would ask if somebody has a similar problem.

[image]

Comment: Had the same problems and switched back to 10.3.1. Quality Central has been unavailable for some days, but there are some contributions to this misconduct.

Comment: Thank you. After days trying it, finally I switched back to 10.3.1. It also has bugs, but at least, the debugger works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug in 10.3.2 and is currently being fixed by Embarcadero.

The bug is tracked as RSP-25527 | RSP-21126 (currently these are marked as duplicates but a request has been made to separate them).

They report that you can work with 64 bit windows ... provided of course you are not trying to link to external libraries or COM objects that are only available as 32 bit.

I can confirm that I have tested a Win64 VCL project and I can confirm that I do have the variables visible in the Inspect Window.  You may have to manually add the 64 bit Windows target.

(I am having some problems with my 64 bit debug setup at the moment - I am loading packages which include debug info (as per the Events window it states the library has debug info) but I am unable to step into some of them which I normally can do with Win32.  I do have the variables visible to me though.)

Comment: If you have access to the Embarcadero quality portal, they released a hot fix for this issue on Friday. I have tried it and I can confirm that with the patch I ***do*** have local variables visible. Quality portal URL: https://quality.embarcadero.com/

Comment: A Further comment - it appears the values shown are not reliable so IMHO you cannot rely on them for debugging purposes.  It may be to do with my project setup (debugging inside a BPL with objects inheriting from another BPL) but I cannot confirm that.